# Deserializing JSON with inheritance

Tags: c#, json, inheritance, json.net

I have a type, Person, that contains an array of additional Persons:

```
public class Person {
  public String FirstName { get; set; }
  public String LastName { get; set; }
  public int Age { get; set; }
  public List<Person> Children { get; internal set; }

  public Person(Person parent)
  {
    if (parent != null) {
      this.LastName = parent.LastName;
    }
  }
}
```

I want to deserialize this from JSON using the NewtonSoft library.

```
{
    FirstName: "George",
    LastName: "Jetson",
    Age: 37,
    Children: [{
        FirstName: "Elroy",
        Age: 7
    }]
}
```

Elroy's last name should be inherited from that outer object. I deserialize this like this:

```
var jetsons = JsonConvert.Deserialize<Person>(json);
```

but the constructor for Elroy gets a null passed to it and therefore doesn't get his last name set.

How can I get the deserializer to pass the parent object as an argument to children's constructor?

Comment: Q: What have you tried?  Could you show us the C#/Json.Net code?  What happens when you execute it?  Does the [documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) or any of the [code samples](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Samples.htm) help?

Answer (score 3):

Just change your Person class as

```
public class Person
{
    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    public String LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public List<Person> Children { get; set; } //<== public setter
}
```

and deserialize as

```
var person = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(json);
```

That is all...

*PS: Of course I assume you use a valid json. (like `FirstName: "George"` instead of `FirstName: George`)*

**EDIT:** 
As mentioned by **@Preston-Guillot**, setting *LastName* to its parent's lastname is your business rule and has nothing to do with the deserialization of your json.

You can rearrange LastNames after deserialization with a recursive code as follows:

```
var person = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(json);

string currLastName = null;
Action<Person> setLastNames = null;
setLastNames = p => {
    currLastName = p.LastName;
    if (p.Children != null) p.Children.ForEach(c => { if (c.LastName == null)  c.LastName = currLastName; });
    if (p.Children != null) p.Children.ForEach(c => setLastNames(c));
};
setLastNames(person);
```

Comment: Children last name is null OP wants the children last name as from the parent

Comment: @believeme Then it should be serialized that way - how it got set initially isn't the concern of the deserializer.